# need to remove lines from syslog that have a certain string of data duplicate

Tags: string, duplicates, lines

hey guys wonder if anyone can help with this little dilema

Trying to remove lines from a syslog text file that have duplicate strings

Mar 10 06:51:11[http-8080-1] INFO com.MYCOMPANY.webservices.userservice.web.UserServiceController [u:2533274802474744|360] Authorize [platformI$tformIdAndOs=2533274802474744|360, userRegion=America|360]

then a few lines down

Mar 10 06:52:03 [http-8080-1] INFO com.MYCOMPANY.webservices.userservice.web.UserServiceController [u:2533274802474744|360] Authorize [platformI$tformIdAndOs=2533274802474744|360, userRegion=America|360

got the same thing in terms of a u: number but the issue is I need to remove duplicates and just leave one and the file has multiple duplicates of different u: numbers and it's 14,000 lines long.

can anyone tell me if I can use awk? sed? or sort for something like this to ? removing lines that have a certain string in there that's a duplicate.

I basically need to de-dupe but the problem is only one little part of the string is the indicator.

Any help is appreciated! thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better way to do this, but here's my first stab at it:

- First, create a new file, call it
  uvalues.txt
- Read the file line by line, for each
  line grep for "u:", store the result
  in $u
- if $u exists in uvalues.txt, ignore
  this line
- if $u does not exist in uvalues.txt, write this line to another file,  write $u to uvalues.txt
- repeat

Code would be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch uvalues.txt

for l in `cat file.txt`; do
        uvalue=`echo "$l" | grep "u:" | cut -f2 -d':' | cut -f1 -d'|'`
        #if uvalue is not empty, check it against our temp file
        if [ -n "$uvalue" ]; then
                existing_value=`grep "$uvalue" uvalues.txt`;
                #if it is empty, it means it's not a duplicate
                if [ -z "$existing_value" ]; then
                        echo $l >> save.txt
                        echo $uvalue >> uvalues.txt
                fi
        fi
done

rm uvalues.txt
```